# ファイル読み込みの際にコンパイルエラーが出ます

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで、ファイルを読み出そうとすると、コンパイルエラーが出ます。

```
import java.util.*; //米印必須。もしくはjava.util.Scanner
import java.io.*;

public class Hanyujiao {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str;

        try {
            
            FileReader file = new FileReader("漢語角.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
            
            String data;
            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                boolean a=data.contains("小河大輔");
                if(a){System.out.println("ファイルの中に小河大輔という文字はあります");}
                System.out.print(data);

                
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // finally{filereader.close();}

    }

}
```

エラー内容は、以下の通りです。

```
エラー: FileInputStreamに適切なコンストラクタが見つかりません(FileReader)
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
                                                                         ^
    コンストラクタ FileInputStream.FileInputStream(String)は使用できません
      (引数の不一致: FileReaderをStringに変換できません:)
    コンストラクタ FileInputStream.FileInputStream(File)は使用できません
      (引数の不一致: FileReaderをFileに変換できません:)
    コンストラクタ FileInputStream.FileInputStream(FileDescriptor)は使用できません
      (引数の不一致: FileReaderをFileDescriptorに変換できません:)
```

FileReaderクラスと、BufferedReaderクラスは併用できないというルールでもあるのでしょうか？

**実行環境**
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileInputStreamのコンストラクタはFile型かString型です。
ご呈示のプログラムはFileReaderを渡しています。だからコンパイルエラーなのです。
明確にAPI仕様に沿っていない。それだけのことです。
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

ご呈示の例では

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("漢語角.txt");
```

を

```
File file = new File("漢語角.txt");
```

とするなどで直接の原因は解決しそうです。